# insert huge list of keywords to mysql with text doc

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge list of keywords in a text doc that I want to dump into my keywords table in mysql. Is there a way I can do this with some sort of php script?

My text doc contains keywords, 1 per line like so:

keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
keyword4
keyword5
etc

I want to be able to dump these keywords into my existing keywords table and not overwrite any possible existing keywords, just add in the new ones. Does anyone know how I could do this?

my table is called keywords, and the columns are keyword_id, keyword, time, total searches. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you write some code and it didn't work or you just don't know where to start?

Comment: I just dont know where to start. I am looking for some idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) if you have the proper permissions in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `keyword_id` column has unique attribute set then read your txt line by line with [fgets()](http://php.net/fgets):

```
$handle = @fopen("huge.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO keywords SET keyword_id = $buffer");
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use load data infile http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

```
load data infile 'keywords.dat' 
into table keywords
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(
 keyword
);
```